# Is CefSharp supported in Mac OS and Linux

Tags: cefsharp

cefsharp page doesn't mention support for operating systems https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage . I know it is supported in Windows. What about Linux and MAC OS? Could anyone please help answering me.

We need to build a application on these 3 operating systems and need to use cef. Trying to keep common code as far as possible

Comment: From the site you linked: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#software-requirements *"CefSharp uses Visual C++(VC++) to interface with the underlying native C++ API, as a result it will only run on Windows."*

Answer (score 2):

CefSharp is Windows only.

CefGlue and Cefnet are alternatives that should work cross platform.

Comment: In Cefnet, Just replacing the cef binary for windows and mac is enough ?

Comment: I'm the CefSharp maintainer, you'll need to ask Cefnet questions on the GitHub project.

Comment: Use puppeteer, I was worked with Cefsharp for long time and I was one of its fans... but someday I must just work with linux in one of my projects and then .... I was found PUPPETEER and found it very better and faster than cefsharp...

Comment: For those using `CefSharp.OffScreen` then [Puppeteer Sharp](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp) is a viable cross platform alternative.